# Show/Hide div in a php include using Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html, include, hide

i have a page called div_1.php with a div inside.

```
 <div id="div_1"></div>
```

i have a page called index.php with:

```
 <div id="div_menu"></div>

<?php include("div_1.php"); ?>
```

Visibility of "div_menu" is true. Default visibility of "div_1" is set to false in style.css.

```
#div_1{
    display: none;
}
```

jQuery function show/hide "div_1":

```
$('.form_name').click(function() {
    // Hide the menu
    $('#div_menu').hide();

    if(this.id == "form_choice1"){
        // Show the div
        $('#div_1').show();
    }
});
```

The first part (hiding "div_menu") works fine but second part doesn't work!!!
if I copy and paste the content of div_1.php into index.php, It works fine !

Why jQuery cannot access to that div?
What is wrong when div is inside a php file?
I thought that php include only make a copy of content of called page inside the calling page.

Comment: I'm assuming you meant `</div>` and not `<!div>`?

Comment: Are you sure div_1.php actually gets included correctly?  Can you see it in Firebug or when you do a "View Source"?

Comment: Can you post more of the code or possibly a full code example? How you have it here should work without any problem.

Comment: Throw and alert statement inside your if statement, make sure it's contents are firing. alert("If Fires")..

Comment: PHP has nothing to do with jquery, unless you're doing an ajax call. It may be php generating the page on the server, but it's just html/css/js reaching the user, NOT php.

Comment: Also, in which order are you including the div_1.php and the javascript function you posted?  It needs to be div_1.php, THEN the JS.  If you have the JS before the include, it will NOT work.

Comment: @Steve, really? Why? I'm assuming that he's using a `$(document).ready()` handler *and* that the included elements from the php page are in the page before it's sent to the browser (and not loaded dynamically). Obviously both those assumptions could be wrong, though.

Comment: @DavidThomas Well, I am not assuming he is using $(document).ready()... If I see <!div>, I am no longer assuming anything. :)  Also, in regards to your second assumption: Even if it is sent to the browser at the same time and the order is wrong, $('div_1') will not find the element (unless he uses $(document).ready()).

Answer (score 0):

You don't appear to be closing your tags properly. This is probably confusing the browser. Format is `</div>` not `<!div>`. Other than that, have you compared the HTML generated by both? They look like they should the same. Check your browser to find the differences.

Comment: I thought this too.. but it works for him when he has it inserted directly into the page. I'm wondering what accounts for that.

Comment: <!div> was only a typing/copy mistake.

I found out that PHP doesn't work on my web server (jetty 8)

Answer (score 0):

I found out that PHP doesn't work on my web server (jetty 8)...

I will try include js files and use document.write function but it is very ugly!